# Security patch SUPEE-6285 - packages_prepare.phtml hunk FAILED - (SOLVED)

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

> patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml Hunk
>   1 FAILED at 33. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file
>   downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml.rej

I apply the patch SUPEE-5994 first as required, but the issue came up anyway.

**First solution** :

Download a fresh version of magento 1.9.2 and replace your packages_prepare.phtml with the fresh packes_prepare.phtml file from the zip.

Then reapply the patch. Instead of "FAILED" you will have the same issue with "IGNORED" because the file already exist with the right content.

**Second Solution** :

Download a fresh archive of Magento 1.8.1 here : http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/noregister

Replace your current packages_prepare.phtml file with fresh one from this archive.

Apply the patch again, and it will works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no one should download patches from unofficial sources.

Comment: Leakover from the Magento boards. One day somebody's going to step on a nail and get infected...

Comment: I changed the source

Answer (score 1):

Please don't download and/or advise to download any patch from outside the official channels, it is a really bad idea.

You don't know if the packages are not modified and that can cause issues in your store, like a security breach or take your entire site down.

Comment: I did check if the file I got after applying the patch was the same as the one in the 1.9.2 version. Anyway, I edited the post.